# Attempted relative import in non-package when running a Python code

Tags: python, github, import, repository, scikit-learn

I an new to Python and am not sure how to run [this code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/cluster/spectral.py). I receive the following error:

```
mona$ python spectral.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "spectral.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ..base import BaseEstimator, ClusterMixin
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package


>>> from ..base import BaseEstimator, ClusterMixin, TransformerMixin
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

I am not sure which other files from that repository should I download or which packages should I download to be able to run this code.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to run that script?

Install scikit-learn.

```
sudo pip install scikit-learn
```

then you can import spectral clustering in your python script:

read: 
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_lena_segmentation.html#example-cluster-plot-lena-segmentation-py

and

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_segmentation_toy.html#example-cluster-plot-segmentation-toy-py

Answer (score 0):

You have to run it as a package not just the componant.

have you already installed the sklearn package and dependancies?

if not you should check out [this page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html) and go from there to install and configure the package.